# $H^1_0$ on half space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that for any $u \in H^1_0(\mathbb R^n_+)$ there holds $u = 0$ on $\partial \mathbb R^n_+$?

How can I prove it?

Comment: $u=0$ makes only sense in the "trace sense" You will have to use traces, see for example Evans book 5.5. Traces theorem 2

Comment: it follows by the continuity of the trace since the functions with compact support approximating $u$ trivially vanish on the boundary

Comment: i agree, this topic can be found in evan's, but he only proves it for **bounded** regions, im particularly asking about an unbounded region

Comment: Yes but I think the argument still holds for the half space

Comment: Clearly all $u\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ satisfy $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial  \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and since there is a sequence $u_j\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ approximating every $u\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ the continuity of the trace $T$ implies $Tu\equiv 0$  and thus $u=0$ on $\partial  \mathbb{R}^n_+$ in the trace sense

Comment: agreed, but the continuity of the trace operator is only guaranteed for bounded domains; that's what im trying to figure out: if one could extend this statement to $\mathbb R^n_+$

Comment: I understand. To me it looks like it´s more about straightening out the boundary but You are right the proof is quite involved there might be some point where You really need the boundedness

Comment: Evans uses the compactness of $\partial U$, for bounded $U$. This might be difficult to fix

Comment: but now im really curious, it should be true though!

Comment: If no bounded trace can be obtained, it is not clear what is ment by $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$. it seems difficult to avoid the argument using the compactness of the boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I gather that your main issue is the continuity (or equivalently the existence) of the trace operator $T:H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$. This is however easy to fix:

We will denote by $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. Consider first $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have 
   $$
   |f(x,0)|^2= \left|\int_0^\infty 2 f(x,t) \partial_t f(x,t)\, dt  \right|.
   $$
   Integrating over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ we arrive at
   \begin{equation}
   \| f(\cdot, 0)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})}^2 \leq 2 \, \| f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n_+)} \, \| \partial_t f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n_+)} \leq 2 \, \| f\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)}^2.
   \end{equation}
2. Now we need to show that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$. To see this we first note that the even extension of $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^{n}_+)$, denoted by $F$, is in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (to prove this work first with $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ functions and then extend by density**) and we have 
   $$
   \| F\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq 2 \| f\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)}.
   $$
   Now the result follows since $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

** Here we're using the Meyers-Serrin Theorem H=W which says that $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$ for any open set $\Omega$ (Evans proof holds in this general case once we have partitions of unity for general open sets, such a construction can be found in many books). Alternatively we could prove this directly by decomposing the upper half-space in cubes or slices of the form $\{ (x,t): 2^{k}<t<2^{k+1}\}$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and constructing appropriate cut-off functions in the $t$-variable.

Comment: was looking for exactly that!